# AngularJS - How to change key value based on dropdown options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am pushing keys to one array and I am iterating it to get options in dropdown.Creating a (key,value) pair, keys in array and options are same. When we change the option in dropdown, the corresponding value should be rendered in HTML.

Here is the code:

```js
$scope.viewItemKeys = [pencils, pens, books];

$scope.viewItemObj = {
    "pencils": {
      "0": {},
      "1": {},
      "2": {}
    },
    "pens": {
      "0": {},
      "1": {},
      "2": {},
      "3": {},
      "4": {}
    },
    "5": {},
    "6": {},
    "7": {}
  },
  "books": {
    "0": {},
    "1": {},
    "2": {},
    "3": {},
    "4": {}
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<select id="selId" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in viewItemkeys" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change='onItemChange()'></select>
```

please help me out if I select pens with respect to key (i.e 1 to 7 , inside pens) I need to render {} value

Comment: You should be binding the select to viewItemObj. ViewItemKeys is an array, you cant create a KV pair out of it.

Comment: @Pratik, when I use like " key as value for (key , value) in viewItemObj ", I got [object Object] as options in dropdown.

Comment: That's because you are using 'as value'. It should be 'as key'. Take a look at my answer below, I have added a fiddler link as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2510/)

Your viewItemObj is a little wrong

```
$scope.viewItemObj = {
"pencils": {
  "0": {},
  "1": {},
  "2": {}
},
"pens": {
  "0": {},
  "1": {},
  "2": {},
  "3": {},
  "4": {},
  "5": {},
  "6": {},
  "7": {}
},
"books": {
  "0": {},
  "1": {},
  "2": {},
  "3": {},
  "4": {}
}
```

};

There was an extra '}' there.
I have modified the HTML as follows

```
<select id="selId" ng-options="value as key for (key , value) in viewItemObj" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change='onItemChange()'></select><br/>
  Selected Item - {{selectedItem | json}}
```

This will render the value of the key that you select.
Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

**EDIT**
Based on your comments I have created a new FIddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/14wkps2c/). This new fiddle will display the values of the selected object.  I have modified the HTML a bit:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select id="selId" ng-options="value as key for (key , value) in viewItemObj" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change='onItemChange()'></select>
  <div ng-repeat="item in selectedItem">
    {{item.Name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also added some dummy data in your object

```
$scope.viewItemObj = {
    "pencils": {
      "0": {
        Name: "Camel"
      },
      "1": {
        Name: "Nataraj"
      },
      "2": {
        Name: "Space"
      }
    },
    "pens": {
      "0": {
        Name: "Camel"
      },
      "1": {
        Name: "Parker"
      },
      "2": {
        Name: "Fountain"
      },
      "3": {
        Name: "Dealer"
      },
      "4": {
        Name: "Gel"
      },
      "5": {
        Name: "Inker"
      },
      "6": {
        Name: "Mountain View"
      },
      "7": {
        Name: "Decor"
      }
    },
    "books": {
      "0": {
        Name: "The Da Vinci Code"
      },
      "1": {
        Name: "How to kill a Mocking Bird"
      },
      "2": {
        Name: "Tooth and Nails"
      },
      "3": {
        Name: "A song of Ice and Fire"
      },
      "4": {
        Name: "Dance with the Dragons"
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for? Or are you looking for a different solution?

Comment: Thanks Prathik and please help me out if I select pens with respect to key (i.e 1 to 7 , inside pens) I need to render {} value

Comment: Ca you please explain your doubt in a little detail? What is it that you need to render when you select 'pens'? Do you need to render the items (like the value of 1,2 ... 7)?

Comment: Take a look at my edit, I think this is what you are looking for. Here is the link to the modified fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/14wkps2c/.

Comment: Exactly!! Thanks a lot @Pratik

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you please mark the answer as correct and upvote it; would be helpful for other users as well.